# 'pos' equivalent when using mtext function

Tags: r, plot, text

I typically use mtext to add labels to figures. I often wish to plot labels in the upper left corner of a figure. This is easy using par('usr')[1], except that the text is centered instead of right-oriented as I want it. When using 'text,' I would use pos=4, but there does not seem to be an equivalent of this for mtext. Example:

```
plot(1)
text(par('usr')[1], 1.5, "test", xpd=TRUE, pos=4)
mtext('test', 3, at=par('usr')[1])
```

I would like to avoid simply adding values to at= or using adj=, since I often am plotting multiple panels with different axes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `adj=` in base plots:

```r
plot(1)
usr <- par("usr")
text(usr[1], usr[3], adj = c(-0.1, -0.1), "lower-left")
text(usr[2], usr[3], adj = c( 1.1, -0.1), "lower-right")
text(usr[1], usr[4], adj = c(-0.1,  1.1), "upper-left")
text(usr[2], usr[4], adj = c( 1.1,  1.1), "upper-right")
```

[image: text with adj]

From `?text`:

> ```
>  adj: one or two values in [0, 1] which specify the x (and
>       optionally y) adjustment ('justification') of the labels,
>       with 0 for left/bottom, 1 for right/top, and 0.5 for
>       centered.  On most devices values outside [0, 1] will also
>       work.  See below.
> ```

I use `-0.1` and `1.1` to inset a little from the margin line itself. The `.1` component might need to be adjusted depending on the rest of the plot.

Comment: darkness1234, does this answer your question? If so, please accept it. Thanks!